# Django iterate all flatpages in a template

Tags: django

how can I get a list of all flatpage objects in a template ?

I am not using development version ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the view that renders the template you want, you can pull all the flatpages from the database. Here's a REALLY crude and far-from-ideal solution:

In the view:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import Flatpage

...do your other view stuff

flatpages = Flatpage.objects.all() 
# You REALLY SHOULD filter() based on other properties of the Flatpages, 
# such as whether or not it requires login to view, or, importantly, 
# which Site it is available on (because not all Flatpages will 
# necessarily be available on the current Site)

...then pass the flatpages queryset into your view
```

In your template:

```
<ul>
{% for flatpage in flatpages %}
     <li><a href="{{flatpage.url}}">{{flatpage.title}}</a></li>      
     {#Note that the page title may not be good link text #} 
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The development version uses a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/?from=olddocs#getting-a-list-of-flatpage-objects-in-your-templates) to get all the flatpage objects in a template. If you want this feature right away you should be able to copy the [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/flatpages/templatetags/flatpages.py) and add it as a custom tag.

Caveat: haven't tested this.